# Is Crawl Error / Google Webmaster Tools Errors and Website having "Request Timed Out" relevant

Tags: drupal-7, web-crawler, google-crawlers, request-timed-out

I have built a Drupal Project and the SEO Tools Modules already implemented in this site, Using the webmaster Tools, I have found a lot of CRAWL Errors and some DNS connectivity errors, which I have fixed, built a Sitemap for the site, and a ROBOTS.txt file, I have validated the speed of the website on the Website Speed Test and validate it on the W3C markup, Other than some images not compressed and missing alt texts I found nothing wrong with the website,

The website is loading too slow, and when I ping it I receive a "Timed OUT Request" and the Peer connectivity is reset,

Could the updates that I have made relevant to each other?! or it is a problem from the Hosting, or the Server?! and how to fix it,

PS: I can't reach the WHM nor the CPANEL,
and the APACHE Server is outdated,

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was after all a hosting issue, they finally replied back to me and they have fixed the issue for now,

Well, any one can recommend a Hosting provider?!

My website is a drupal project, SQL, APACHER and off course PHP  :)